# Clone and append div after nearest article

Tags: jquery

In Wordpress I'm looking to duplicate the title of each Wordpress post and place it below the nearest article (by default it's only shown above).

This code almost works, but it removes the title from the top instead of cloning it:

```
$("h2.entry-title").each(function() {
  $(this).closest("article.post").append(this);
});
```

Is there anyway to clone (this) and append the copy without removing the original?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `clone` function for cloning elements:

```
$("h2.entry-title").each(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.closest("article.post").append($this.clone());
});
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Opted for this answer as it was nearest to my original jQuery attempt (thus easier for me to understand and change later). I appreciate the other responses probably also work. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

Usually in WordPress the `.entry-title` heading tag is a child of its corresponding `article.post` so you can have the javascript code written like this:

[**JS Fiddle 1**](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/hw7wt484/)

```js
$('h2.entry-title').each(function() {
  $(this).parents('article.post').append($(this).clone());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article class="post">
  <h2 class="entry-title">FIRST test header</h2>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsam omnis ullam non dolores dolore placeat eligendi nulla id et deserunt consectetur adipisci natus vel nisi vero, perferendis, nihil veritatis odit.
</article>
<hr>
<article class="post">
  <h2 class="entry-title">SECOND test header</h2>
  Ipsam omnis ullam non dolores dolore placeat eligendi nulla id et deserunt consectetur adipisci natus vel nisi vero, perferendis, nihil veritatis odit.
</article>
```

---

Alternatively, *as the `.closest()` didn't work for me no matter how I tried to use it*, the below would mostly work too even if the `.entry-title` is outside its respective `article.post` but with one exception<sup>(*)</sup>.

[**JS Fiddle 2**](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/k5702u0z/3/)

```js
var clones = $('h2.entry-title'),
  articles = $('article.post');

clones.each(function(i) {
  $(articles[i]).append($(this).clone());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article class="post">
  <h2 class="entry-title">FIRST test header</h2>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsam omnis ullam non dolores dolore placeat eligendi nulla id et deserunt consectetur adipisci natus vel nisi vero, perferendis, nihil veritatis odit.
</article>
<hr>
<!-- Note that this header is outside its corresponding article -->
<h2 class="entry-title">SECOND test header</h2>
<article class="post">
  Ipsam omnis ullam non dolores dolore placeat eligendi nulla id et deserunt consectetur adipisci natus vel nisi vero, perferendis, nihil veritatis odit.
</article>
```

---

<sup>(*)</sup> - in case of having the `h2.entry-title` *outside* its respective `article.post` the order of the `.entry-title` heading tag relative to other heading tag on the DOM *must* be *same as* the order of that `.post` article to other articles in the DOM.

For example: you can't have the 2nd `h2.entry-title` *before* the 1st `h2.entry-title` in the DOM while having the 2nd `article.post` *after* the 1st `article.post` tag.